# converting the C# code to python on decryption

Tags: python, c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public Task<byte[]> Decrypt(byte[] encryptedBytes, string encryptionKey)
{
    if (encryptedBytes == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("encryptedBytes can't be null");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptionKey))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("encryptionKey can't be null");

    byte[] encryptedTextBytes = encryptedBytes;
    this._encryptionKey = encryptionKey;

    var encryptionKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(this._encryptionKey);
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes generatedKey = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(this._encryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x65, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x65 });
    var sessionKey = generatedKey.GetBytes(32);
    var iV = generatedKey.GetBytes(16);

    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return (Decrypt(encryptedTextBytes, sessionKey, iV));

    });
}

public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] dataToDecrypt, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        aes.Key = key;
        aes.IV = iv;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            cryptoStream.Write(dataToDecrypt, 0, dataToDecrypt.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            var decryptBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

            return decryptBytes;
        }
    }
}
```

Hi,
I need help converting the above-mentioned c# code to its equivalent python code. As I am new to python, hence not sure which are the relevant libraries to be used here. It would be great if someone could help me here.

So far I have tried the below code but looks like it is not working:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
from PIL import Image
_encryptionKey='secret'.encode("utf-32")
salt = '\0x65\0x76\0x61\0x6e\0x20\0x4d\0x65\0x64\0x76\0x65\0x64\0x65\0x65'.encode("utf-32")
key_bytes = PBKDF2(_encryptionKey, salt, dkLen=64)
session_key=key_bytes[:32]
iv= key_bytes[:16]
cipher = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
val = cipher.decrypt(ency_img)
Image.open(BytesIO(val))
```

Here `ency_img` is encrypted image bytes object coming from the MySQL DB with column type as `longblob`

error from PIL Image

> PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO
> object at 0x7fb10d79a270>

Comment: can you compare the decrypted bytes between the `c#` version and the `python` version?

Comment: @WhiteWizard, Yes, currently working on it

Comment: For an analysis of the encryption, the corresponding overload of `Decrypt()` (the one with the *three* parameters) is missing in the C# code. Regarding the key derivation, in the Python code in the salt all `\0x` must be replaced by `\x` and key and salt must be UTF-8 encoded (instead of UTF-32). The IV results from the 16 bytes following the first 32 bytes: `key_bytes[32:32+16]`.

Comment: @Topaco yes you are right, I missed the overload of Decrypt which I have added now. I have tried the suggested changes but still the same error of PIL.

Comment: Both codes decrypt with AES in CBC mode. However, in the C# code the PKCS#7 padding is removed implicitly, while in the Python code this must happen explicitly. For this PyCryptodome has the [`Padding`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-padding-module) module: `unpad(val, 16)`. This should also be fixed (even if it also works with padding).

Comment: @Topaco my bad that in the code while trying out things, I had changed the `AES.MODE_CBC` to `AES.MODE_CFB` which was causing the problem now it is fine after reverting.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to this question with the help of @Topaco's comment. Thank you, buddy.

As mentioned in the comment of @Topaco, I had to do the following changes:

1. replace the `\0x` with `\x`
2. change encodings of `_encryptionKey` and `salt` to `utf-8` instead of `utf-32`
3. value of `iv` as `key_bytes[32:32+16]` instead of `key_bytes[:16]`

Below is the working code for me:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
from PIL import Image

_encryptionKey='secret'.encode("utf-8")
salt = '\x65\x76\x61\x6e\x20\x4d\x65\x64\x76\x65\x64\x65\x65'.encode("utf-8")
key_bytes = PBKDF2(_encryptionKey, salt, dkLen=64)
session_key=key_bytes[:32]
iv= key_bytes[32:32+16]
cipher = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(val))
print(img.size)
Image.open(BytesIO(val))
```

Hope this would help somebody